# Is there a way to warn about this pointer bug?

Tags: c

The situation is that I have an array of `struct`

```
tree_t tree[MAXTREES];
```

and I have been using a pointer to access the array's elements

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAXTREES; i++) {
    tree_t *tptr = tree + i;
    // ...
}
```

To make the code easier to manage - compare these simple examples:

```
int num;
num = tree[i].node[j].left;     // could be like this
num = tptr->node[j].left;       // but I am using this
```

That's the situation, but I made a bug by mistakenly typing

```
num = tree->node[j].left;
```

and because the array decays to a pointer to its first element, it's valid C code and it took me a while to spot what I had done wrong.

Is there a way to get a warning about this? Or is it just poor programming style?

Here is a compilable example, it's not worth actually runnning.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAXLEAFS     16384
#define MAXTREES     15262

typedef struct {
    int16_t left;
    int16_t right;
} leaf_t;

typedef struct tree_t {
    leaf_t node[MAXLEAFS];
    int spudbase;
    int root;
    int width;
    int spudics;
    struct tree_t *nextree;
} tree_t;

tree_t tree[MAXTREES];

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXTREES; i++) {
        tree_t *tptr = tree + i;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXLEAFS; j++) {
            int num;
            num = tree[i].node[j].left;     // could be like this
            num = tptr->node[j].left;       // but I am using this
            num = tree->node[j].left;       // this is my bug
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: To illustrate why I am doing this, here is a snippet of my actual code, which I simplified to ask the question. I am using a pointer to the `struct` to avoid nesting the array indexing here:

```
tree[index].spudics = tree[index].node[tree[index].root].left + 
                      tree[index].node[tree[index].root].right;
```

and simplify with

```
tptr->spudics = tptr->node[tptr->root].left + tptr->node[tptr->root].right;
```

which IMO is more readable.

Comment: Does compiling with `-Wall` give you any warnings?

Comment: @tadman It's MSVC

Comment: Turn on more warnings, then.

Comment: @tadman so gcc would issue a warning for this with `-Wall`?

Comment: I'm not sure it will, as `tree->node` is is basically `tree[0].node` but you never know what warnings you might have available until you check. The compiler won't be able to detect when you write valid code that isn't what you intended, so that's on you.

Comment: I'll post a MRE soon.

Comment: In what way does that "make the code easier to manage"?!  Demonstrably it does not, because of the bug you created.  There that that, it is a semantic error, not a syntactic error.  It means the same as `tree[0].node[j].left;` which may be intentional, the compiler cannot read your mind.

Comment: @Clifford I simplified it, that's not the question. Perhaps I am guilty of premature optimisation: I don't want the compiler to continually calculate the address of an array.

Comment: @tadman I posted the MRE.

Comment: I don't think there is a warning for this, but it would be good if someone would implement this. One of misdesigns of C. I am afraid only testing can help you - it can find this and many other issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is an avoidable problem. If you rewrite this to use iterator pointers you get code like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    tree_t *tptr = tree;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXTREES; ++i, ++tptr) {
        leaf_t *leaf = tptr->node;

        for (int j = 0; j < MAXLEAFS; ++j, ++leaf) {
            int num = leaf->left;
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids a lot of problems because you're using very focused pointers and there's really no reason to do things like `leaf[j].left` by accident. The correct code looks simple. The incorrect code *looks* broken.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't answer the question. I simplified my real code for the sake of the example. I am using a pointer to the `struct` to avoid nesting the array indexing here: `tree[index].spudics = tree[index].node[tree[index].root].left + tree[index].node[tree[index].root].right;` and simplify with `tptr->spudics = tptr->node[tptr->root].left + tptr->node[tptr->root].right;` which IMO makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: I strongly disagree. That is way, way harder to follow. There's a reason trees like this usually use pointers instead of numerical indexes. It makes the implementation simpler.

Comment: Thank you, but I did use a pointer, in preference to the nested array indexing, as added to the question.

Comment: I apologise for misleading you. The example code was purely an example to see if someone's gcc produced a warning. It is not functional code, as I hinted. I make a simple example and everyone says "but you would not do it like that." I didn't: the true code was given as an "edit". Yes, I could have made a pointer for the two `node` accesses in the added more complex code, but the original bug would be the same.

Comment: I'm saying if you do need to use the original structure then write code that makes it harder to foul up by accident. The compiler cannot and will not report on situations where the code is syntactically valid yet does something contradictory to your intentions. As a C programmer that is your implicit responsibility to get right. In other words: Make the right way clean and the wrong way ugly. You'll spot errors faster.

Comment: I disagree: some compilers will warn about `if(a = b)` and `if(a | b)` on the grounds that the valid code may not have been what was intended. I was asking if a compiler should warn about an implicit access of the first element of an array, when that might not be (and in this case wasn't) intended.

Comment: Sure, there's always exceptions to the rule, but in general, no. In this case you're asking a lot of the compiler.